# Problems with running a Java project under Tomcat after an Eclipse crash

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, tomcat

This might be the ultimate newbie question, but I am really in a hurry and need a quick fix.

I have a Java project which I develop under Eclipse, and run under Tomcat, using the Eclipse plugin. Until last night everything was sound and fine. Then, I got an Eclipse error, which made me kill the Eclipse process ... and this morning, the project does not want to run.

It compiles, but as if Tomcat has no idea of my project library folder. When I run it, it starts screaming "class not found" exceptions. I did a little experiment of moving my project libs directly into Tomcat's library folder - it works, so clearly the problem lies in Tomcat, not recognizing my project lib folder any longer.

I tried cleaning the project, refreshing it and whatnot, but still the problem persists. I don't want libs t remain a direct possession Tomcat, because that makes a series of other problems and complications. I just want things back as they were last night before the crash.

Comment: Did you check your buildpath (.classpath file)?

Comment: Eclipse is notoriously bad at recovering from crashes.  In the past a crash could mean having to completely reinstall the IDE.  I'm not sure how to fix this issue, though in general I would suggest moving away from Eclipse to some more robust build-management tools (Maven, Ivy, Ant, etc.).  Then you can continue to develop in Eclipse, without the risk of having your entire build get screwed if something bad happens and Eclipse freaks out.

Comment: @aroth I am definitely moving to Maven, once I have some free time to hook myself into it. I've read lots of great stuff about it, and it seems that every major Java project is using it. I am just lacking experience with Maven, so I am still pushing project management, the only way that Eclipse provides - manually :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that seems to have worked - go to the Server view, right-click, then "Clean Tomcat working directory". It has always been there, I must have just been too hectic before to notice it.

Comment: As with cleaning the project, cleaning the Tomcat server fixes all manner of issues. Note, the reason cleaning the server worked where cleaning the project didn't, is because Eclipse publishes your web projects to a location that's separate from your project location (within the  [workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core folders by default